# How do I update record of DataExtension in SFMC and trigger a push notification if certain criteria are met?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, mobilepush

I need to understand if this is possible to implement the following flow in Marketing Cloud.

1. A User opens mobile app and performs some action. A new record to custom object ( I guess to custom DataExtension) should be created with some fields\columns populated.

Should I use SOAP API for this like the following?

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
     <soap:Header>
          <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1">
               <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="SecurityToken-6421ac0b-a454-42a3-99f7-a77ace024446">
                                                      <wsse:Username>XXXXX</wsse:Username>
                    <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXXXX</wsse:Password>     
               </wsse:UsernameToken>
          </wsse:Security>
     </soap:Header>
     <soap:Body>
          <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
               <Options/>
                    <Objects xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">
                         <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                         <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                         <CustomerKey>Definition_Key</CustomerKey>
                         <Properties>
                              <Property>
                                   <Name>EmailAddress</Name>
                                   <Value>johndoe@example.com</Value>
                        </Property>
                        <Property>
                        <Name>FirstName</Name>
                           <Value>John</Value>
                        </Property>
                        <Property>
                           <Name>LastName</Name>
                           <Value>Doe</Value>
                        </Property>
                        <Property>
                           <Name>PrimaryKey</Name>
                           <Value>PrimaryKey</Value>
                        </Property>
                    </Properties>
                 </Objects>
        </CreateRequest>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Does some REST API Method exist which accomplishes the same task?

2. Once a record is updated in Marketing Cloud, a mobile push should be sent back to mobile device if certain criteria are met, for example, `Column1` value on DataExtension record is `value1` and `Column2` value on DataExtension record is `value2` or `Column3` value on DataExtension record is `value3`.

I don't understand if this can be accomplished with [MobilePush feature](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_mp_outbound_message.htm&type=5)

How do I write a trigger in Marketing Cloud? Is this possible at all? Are there some other means in Marketing Cloud which correspond to trigger, workflow, process builders in Salesforce?